# Как скомпилировать .py в .exe 32-bit на 64-bit системе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Надо скомпилировать .py в .exe но что-бы файл получился 32-bit, при условии что у меня стоит 64-bit система, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте ответ здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988772/create-32-bit-exes-from-python-code-on-64-bit-machine/18043350

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачать x32 Python и можешь не удаляя установить другой python(x32) в Переменной **PATH**.
2. Когда ты это сделаешь, зайди в консоль и напиши: `pip install pyinstaller`.
3. Перейди в свою локацию с помощью команды в *cmd* `cd`.
4. Пиши `pyinstaller -f file.py`.
5. Перейдите в папку *dist* и там ваш *.exe.

P.s.: там где `file.py` укажите имя вашей проги.

Answer (score 0):

Я в таком случае делал так, удалял Python x64, шёл на сайт Python.org и скачивал дистрибутив х32, устанавливал и компилировал
Всё получалось удачно. Советую попробовать, другого способа увы не знаю
P.s при использовании этого способа придётся переустанавливать все библиотеки

Comment: Несколько версий Python могут находиться на одном компьютере без всяких проблем.